# PayPal Pro Hosted payment page - disable 'Pay by PayPal' on payment page

Tags: php, paypal

I have implemented PayPal Pro Hosted payment gateway on our site. I have two buttons on our site, 'Pay by Card' and 'Pay by PayPal'. Hence we want to disable the 'Pay with my PayPal account' option from the 'PayPal Pro Payment' page.

Please let me know how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Neha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove "pay by paypal" option from the iframe page. For sandbox account, please contact PayPal technical team at www.paypal-techsupport.com , they can disable this option for you.For live account, you need to contact PayPal customer service to apply this.